# How to get download progress of an IFRAME

Tags: javascript, iframe, download, progress-bar

I would like to display a progress of downloading some document inside an iframe. I've created this [JavaScript progress bar](http://codecanyon.net/item/progress-bar/full_screen_preview/168054) and now I want to use it as a download progress indicator. I know it's possible when used with ajax, but what about loading file/document in a traditional way.

I've tried to search inside MSDN for the solution and I'm now wondering if I could use any of these:

- window.onreadystatechange / document.onreadystatechange
- document.onprogress event - I'm not sure if it's supported by other browsers than IE and if it's applied to download progress at all.

or should I look somewhere else...?

Comment: If i was trying to build it, i'd go for the onreadystatechange solution.

Comment: it gives me an info only about 2 states: "loading" and "complete"... I'm afraid it's not enough for a progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

Well... 11 years later, I see it goes unanswered, but your progress bar still exists!

I was looking for the same thing and ended up using a fetch, implementing this enhancement: https://github.com/AnthumChris/fetch-progress-indicators/blob/master/fetch-enhanced/supported-browser.js

This piece of code checks the amount of data read of fetch response against the content-length header, and turns it into an easy to use hook. One can also implement something similar themselves, if preferred.

Then you can do something like:

```
let progress = 0;
const fetcher = new ProgressReportFetcher({loaded, total} => {
  progress = (loaded / total) * 100;
});

let iframeSrc;
fetcher.fetch(resourceUrl)
  .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then((arrayBuffer) => new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: 'application/pdf' })) // see note below
  .then((blob) => window.URL.createObjectURL(blob))
  .then((url) => {
    iframeSrc = url;
  });
```

(Or, if you want to port it back to javascript 11 years ago, some jquery variant of this...)

N.b., I turned it into a PDF here. You need to set the mimetype when making the blob, otherwise you see garbled data, and the native [response.blob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/blob) method unfortunately does not support doing this. Hence the extra jump through the arrayBuffer.